# frequent add/updates of files on CDN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I was using GCP cloud storage.
But there is a limit on how frequently you can update. I need to add/update 10000 pages per minute.

[Quotas & limits  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#buckets)

Any other options with GCP or any other CDN to achieve frequent updates?

Answer (score 1):

**Adding pages** can be quite different to **updating pages**.

For example, **Amazon CloudFront** is a 'pull' cache, so it only caches pages when a user requests the page and it only caches it in the region/edge location of the user who made the request.

Thus, there is no action required when new pages are added to your origin.

If, however, you want to invalidate a page that has been cached, it would cost $0.005 per path requested for invalidation (after the first 1000 paths each month). Thus, it would be expensive to invalidate thousands of pages per minute.

You might instead consider using a low Time-to-Live (TTL) and simply having pages expire themselves.

Comment: and TTL expiry won't cost us, even if we keep TTL to 30 or 60 mins